# How to parse brackets [] in URLs in phpbb

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

Is it even possible to parse a link (url) that has square brackets in it since phpbb uses these for there BBcode?

Im not talking about the BBcode [url]www.google.com[/url] but just links like www.google.com/foo[test]end

If it is possible in phpbb where and how would I go about doing this? (which file)

I found an example for **drupal**, which I might be able to use there regex, but I still don't know which file and what to edit... http://drupal.org/node/190466

Comment: Your introduction suggests that you have managed to find an implementation that works on urls without brackets. If so, how did you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at JIRA for phpbb3   [here](http://tracker.phpbb.com/browse/PHPBB3-8082)